# net.sf.json.JSONException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role

Tags: hibernate, rest

`net.sf.json.JSONException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: dao.entities.CourseMaster.chapterCourseMappings, no session or session was closed`

**My Entity:**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "course_master")
    public class CourseMaster implements Serializable {

private Integer id;
private String courseName;
private String category;
private Set<CourseWeightage> courseWeightages = new HashSet<CourseWeightage>();
private Set<ChapterCourseMapping> chapterCourseMappings = new HashSet<ChapterCourseMapping>();

public CourseMaster() {
}

public CourseMaster(String courseName, String category) {
    this.courseName = courseName;
    this.category = category;
}

public CourseMaster(String courseName, String category,
        Set<CourseWeightage> courseWeightages, Set<ChapterCourseMapping> chapterCourseMappings) {
    this.courseName = courseName;
    this.category = category;
    this.courseWeightages = courseWeightages;
    this.chapterCourseMappings = chapterCourseMappings;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "course_name", nullable = false, length = 100)
public String getCourseName() {
    return this.courseName;
}

public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
    this.courseName = courseName;
}

@Column(name = "category", nullable = false, length = 2)
public String getCategory() {
    return this.category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "courseMaster")
public Set<CourseWeightage> getCourseWeightages() {
    return this.courseWeightages;
}

public void setCourseWeightages(Set<CourseWeightage> courseWeightages) {
    this.courseWeightages = courseWeightages;
}


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "courseMaster")
public Set<ChapterCourseMapping> getChapterCourseMappings() {
    return this.chapterCourseMappings;
}

public void setChapterCourseMappings(Set<ChapterCourseMapping> chapterCourseMappings) {
    this.chapterCourseMappings = chapterCourseMappings;
}
}
```

**Controller Method:** (RESTful Web Service API)

**Potential Operations in Method causing Exception!**

```
    net.sf.json.JSONObject data = new net.sf.json.JSONObject();

    List<CourseMaster> alrCourseMasters = genericBusiness.getCourses();

    data.put("courselist", alrCourseMasters);

    view = new Viewable("/test.jsp", data);

    return Response.status(200).entity(view).build();
```

**DAO Method:**

```
public List<CourseMaster> getCourses() 
{
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from CourseMaster");
    List<CourseMaster> alrCourseMasters = query.list();
    transaction.commit();
    session.flush();
    session.close();
    return alrCourseMasters;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are serializing the Object into the string, you should have eager initializing in your associated hibernate entities.

in your case,

```
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "courseMaster")
public Set<ChapterCourseMapping> getChapterCourseMappings() {
return this.chapterCourseMappings;
}
```

rename to as below

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "courseMaster")
public Set<ChapterCourseMapping> getChapterCourseMappings() {
return this.chapterCourseMappings;
}
```

Also check all associations should be eager fetch.

OR ELSE you can use create SQlQueries in hibernate and map that result to some pojo and convert that into json string. it will works.